# Como mostrar resultado de consulta em banco dentro de um JtextArea

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

como faço pra exibir os dados de uma consulta em um banco, dentro de um JtextArea? fiz todo o meu método de listar(que está na classe CarroDAO), e quero que ele mostre os dados dentro do textArea(que está na classe Tela)

segue o código:

**Classe Carro DAO com o método de listar:**

```
@Override
public ArrayList<Carro> listar() {

    ArrayList<Carro> carros= new ArrayList<Carro>();
    String sql="select * from carro";

try(Connection con= new ConnectionFactory().getConnection()){

    PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs= null;

    rs=ps.executeQuery();

    while(rs.next()) {

        Carro c= new Carro();

        //pegando os dados da tabela
        c.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
        c.setMarca(rs.getString("marca"));
        c.setModelo(rs.getString("modelo"));
        c.setCor(rs.getString("cor"));
        c.setPlaca(rs.getString("placa"));

        carros.add(c);
    }   

    ps.close();
    rs.close();

}catch(SQLException e){

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao realziar consulta:"+e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);

}
    return carros;
}
```

**Classe Tela com o JtextArea:**

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();


    //Jscrollpane:
    //colocando o text area dentro do ScrollPane
    jspane= new JScrollPane(textArea);
    jspane.setBounds(286, 48, 162, 170);
    contentPane.add(jspane);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Após iniciar o componente, basta criar um laço que varrerá toda a lista retornada pelo seu método, semelhante ao abaixo:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();


//Jscrollpane:
//colocando o text area dentro do ScrollPane
jspane= new JScrollPane(textArea);
jspane.setBounds(286, 48, 162, 170);
contentPane.add(jspane);

ArrayList<Carro> carros = dao.listar();

for(Carro c :  carros) {
   textArea.append(String.valueOf(c.getId()));
   textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
   textArea.append(c.getMarca());
   textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
   textArea.append(c.getModelo());
   textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
   textArea.append(c.getCor());
   textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
   textArea.append(c.getPlaca());
   textArea.append("===========");
   textArea.append(System.lineSeparator());
}
```

O método `System.lineSeparator()` insere uma quebra de linha entre cada propriedade.

Lembrando que `dao` deve ser uma instancia já iniciada da sua classe `CarroDAO` onde o método `listar()` se encontra.

Comment: @Viny_Hidan veja a edição que fiz, agora está bem claro como você pode fazer.